# Install autoconf 2.69 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-installation

The default version of `autoconf` in 12.04 is version 2.8. How can I upgrade to autoconf 2.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PPA: [`ppa:costamagnagianfranco/autoconf` [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~costamagnagianfranco/+archive/autoconf)

For information on how to PPAs see: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ppa:costamagnagianfranco PPA is no longer active or at least didn't work for me.

Instead there is a PPA available for a lot of GNU libraries at https://launchpad.net/~dns/+archive/ubuntu/gnu

For example this allowed me to install Autoconf 2.69 on Travis:

```
before_script:
  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dns/gnu -y
  - sudo apt-get update -q
  - sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade autoconf
```